# any suggestion for a dropdownlist filter with a textbox?

Tags: asp.net

I have a page in ASP.NET that needs to have a single control like a combobox or dropdownlist that is filtered when input is typed in a textbox. On page load, I am getting the list items from a datatable (DB2). I used to utilize this before with a Telerik combobox but then i am doing a project with no third party controls. any suggestions?

Comment: You mention classic ASP but you tag ASP.NET. Currently your question is too broad, what have you tried, any issues so far?

Comment: sorry. made the change already. thanks.

Comment: i prefer this approach:

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

but then i want to use my own UI or CSS.

Comment: So what is it @OwenMills Classic ASP or ASP.Net, what do you term as a *"classic ASP.Net"* page? Are you speaking about [tag:asp.net-webforms] perhaps? Either way it shouldn't be tagged [tag:asp-classic] that is something entirely different.

Comment: "Classic ASP.Net" is an oxymoron. Show us the code you have so far, maybe that'll help us figure out whether you're using *classic asp* vs. *asp.net*.

Comment: @Martha reading between the lines and use of phrases like *"page load"* and *"datatable"* it's likely ASP.Net but worth getting clarification.

Comment: Someone else edited asp-cassic tag back in.  Removed as it is asp.net

Comment: thanks for the clarification. i apologize because i am not entirely knowledgeable on the details.